# How to Enable Parallel Deployment In Weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

Has Anyone have tried to do a parallel deployment in weblogic 12.2.1?

I have been reading the documents that weblogic 12.2.1 can do parallel deployment [Here the link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/DEPGD/managing.htm#DEPGD491)

and i have no idea to configure `ParallelDeployApplications`

Please help by the way im just a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it is enable but if you want to check if it is enable use [WebLogic Scripting Tool](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/06-WLST--4474/cmdline.htm). Once you configure every thing locate their `ParallelDeployApplications` typically its a Boolean type.

**Note**: Dont forget to save and activate your changes